# Unable to start rails server: No Rails found in SDK/ Can't activate bundler-1.25.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rubymine

I'm using rubymine from jetbrains and when trying to run rails server by clicking on `Run --> Run 'Development: HelloWorld'`, its saying:

> Error running Development: HelloWorld: [No Rails found in SDK]

I checked in `File --> Default Settings... --> Languages & Frameworks --> Ruby SDK and Gems`, I was using `rbenv 2.3.1` as expected and every gems were up to date, I didn't have to update them. So I tried to do this manually by running

```
rails server
```

on the terminal and I got a list of errors:

> /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2278:in `check_version_conflict': can't activate bundler-1.12.5, already activated bundler-1.13.0.rc.1 (Gem::LoadError)
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1404:in`activate'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:68:in `block in gem'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in`synchronize'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `gem'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/postit_trampoline.rb:32:in`'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/config/boot.rb:3:in`'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/bin/rails:8:in`'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`call'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in`run'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in`load'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>           from /Users/emilychiu/RubymineProjects/HelloWorld/bin/spring:13:in`'
>           from bin/rails:3:in `load'
>           from bin/rails:3:in`'

I tried doing the steps in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269526/switched-from-rbenv-from-rvm-and-now-not-able-to-rails-s-cant-activate-bundler) and running `rails server` again gave me the same error.

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.6
- RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-darwin15]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/emilychiu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/emilychiu/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-darwin-15
- GEM PATHS:
   - /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
   - /Users/emilychiu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
   - /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
   - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec
   - /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/shims
   - /Users/emilychiu/.rbenv/bin
   - /bin
   - /usr/bin
   - /sbin
   - /usr/sbin
   - /usr/local/bin
$ gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.12.5
1 gem installed
$ rbenv rehash
$ bundle --path=vendor/bundle
Using rake 11.2.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using minitest 5.9.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using pkg-config 1.1.7
Using rack 2.0.1
Using nio4r 1.2.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 7.1.1
Using byebug 9.0.5
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using thor 0.19.1
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using ffi 1.9.14
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.7
Using puma 3.6.0
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using spring 1.7.2
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using sprockets 3.7.0
Using websocket-driver 0.6.4
Using mime-types 3.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.1
Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using activesupport 5.0.0
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using listen 3.0.8
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.1
Using globalid 0.3.7
Using activemodel 5.0.0
Using jbuilder 2.6.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.0
Using activejob 5.0.0
Using activerecord 5.0.0
Using actionview 5.0.0
Using actionpack 5.0.0
Using actioncable 5.0.0
Using actionmailer 5.0.0
Using railties 5.0.0
Using sprockets-rails 3.1.1
Using coffee-rails 4.2.1
Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
Using web-console 3.3.1
Using rails 5.0.0
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 63 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
```

When I run `rails server` again, it still gives me the same error. Any idea on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To run Rails server in Rubymine, use hotkey `ctrl+alt+R` instead of the **Run** menu (see this manual https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.2/running-rails-server.html ).

Outside of Rubymine, it seems your latest bundler is `1.13.0.rc.1`, while (maybe) `Gemfile.lock` is looking for `1.12`. Try `gem uninstall bundler -v 1.13.0.rc.1`, then run `bundle exec rails server` or `bundle exec rails s` again.